# Django - can't add ints records to ints in dictionaries?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, record

**This has to be my misunderstanding - I'm looking to learn here. Any help is appreciated.**

I'm getting a type error when trying to add integers looping over a set of Django Object Records, and I have no idea why.

---

I've got a database full of date-stamped values. I want to sum the values of appropriate fields together to get a daily total, while acknowledging that there won't be records for each day for each product. E.g. :

```
Product A has sales on May 11, 12, and 14
Product B has sales on May 6, 11, 14 and 19
```

What I want to end up with is an array of sequential sales totals that I can then graph. For this graph I don't care about the date, I want the trend. I already have that working for individual products, but am trying to make it work with total sales for collections of products.

I feel like this is pretty standard stuff.

My records look something like this:

```
Data_Record:
product_id | product_family | datetime | daily_sales | daily_profit
```

---

### Current Solution

```
product_family_totals = {}

for Data_Record in Records_From_Table:

   if Data_Record.product_family not in product_family_totals.keys():
      product_family_total[Data_Record.product_family] = {}

   if Data_Record.date not in product_family_totals[Data_record.product_family]:
      product_family_total[Data_record.product_family][Data_Record.date] = {
       'sales' : Data_Record.daily_sales,
       'profit': Data_record.daily_profit }
   else:
      product_family_total[Data_record.product_family][Data_Record.date]['sales'] += Data_Record.daily_sales
      product_family_total[Data_record.product_family][Data_Record.date]['profit'] += Data_Record.daily_profit
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

**This is really weird, because when I check the type of each item they're both integers.**

```
print(f"Data_Record.daily_sales is {type(Data_Record.daily_sales)}")
print(f"product_family->daily_sales {type( product_family_total[Data_record.product_family][Data_Record.date]['sales'])}")
```

Results in

```
Data_Record.daily_sales is type <class 'int'>
product_family->daily_sales is type <class 'int'>
```

---

### Horrible Work Around

I **can** add these values together and put them into my result dict like this

```
... 
 else:
     x = product_family_total[Data_record.product_family][Data_Record.date]['sales']
     y = Data_Record.daily_sales
     z = x + y
    product_family_total[Data_record.product_family][Data_Record.date]['sales'] = z
```

... but that's just wrong.

---

I admit I'm an older coder, but can someone help me understand what's happening here? This seems completely ***bonkers*** to me!

Comment: What is the `.` doing in `Data_Record.`? Is there something missing here?

Comment: That's how you access fields within records inside QuerySets in Django.


e.g. 

`products = models.Product.objects.filter(product_family=product_family_id)



for product in products:
print(f"totals sales for this product on {product.datetime} was {product.daily_sales}")`

Comment: but at the last line, you write `+= Data_Record.` (with nothing else). That does not make much sense.

Comment: Good catch - that's my bad typing! Thanks, Willem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aren't you accidentally leave any . or , in your code? i faced this problem one time and the reason was this:

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 17 2020, 14:48:56) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 4
>>> x += y,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: My goodness. You're right.

While writing I had copied the code under the IF statement into the ELSE clause!

Feeling pretty stupid, but thank you so much!

Thank you!

Comment: I would upvote you, but I'm so new I'm not allowed. So here's an upvote for you:

UPVOTE!